# A basic question on the algebraic dimension of an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

Let $W,V\subset \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be irreducible varieties both of dimension $n$ defined as the $0$-sets of some prime ideals $I$, $J$ on $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_{2n}]$, ideals which remains prime in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_{2n}]$.
Assume $p=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{2n})$ is an isolated point of 
$V\cap W$. Is the transcendence degree of the numbers $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{2n}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ equal to $n$? i.e. equal to the geometric dimension of $V$? 
Or in general this is not the case?

Comment: Irreducible varieties can't have isolated points, except in the trivial case that the variety is a point. Do you mean something different?

Comment: sorry my question as posed is flawed I reedit it.

Comment: probably it remains a rather dumb question…. Nonetheless I've very little familiarity with the subject and I fall almost immediately in false traps….

Comment: There's obvious counterexamples here- take $W=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $V=(x_{n+1},\cdots,x_{2n})$. The only point in their intersection is $(0,\cdots,0)$.